# Role of "the" in "the one thing that can be done is to provide opportunity"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

In the extract

> **The** one thing that can be done is to provide opportunity, without repining at the waste that results from most men failing to make good use of the opportunity.

does removing the emboldened article "the" cause any change in the meaning? As far as I know, "one" is a determiner for "thing" and so "one thing that can be done" is a valid noun phrase.

Comment: Removing *the* admits the possibility that there are other things that can be done.

Comment: @Lawrence, Thanks. Can it be rephrased as "the only thing that can be done..."?

Comment: It could, but as KarlG's answer points out, there is also the nuance that the special quality of that 'one thing' might be its effectiveness / practicality / importance / etc, not necessarily that it is unique in an absolute sense.

Answer (score 3):

Removing the article suggests:

> One thing [among various options] that can be done...

while retaining it means:

> The one [most important, most vital] thing that can be done...